# How To Add Item ToSharePoint List Programmaitcally

Tags: development, custom-list, list-item

My goal is to simply submit a new item to a SharePoint list programmatic-ally through a custom web part that I'm building, however, I'm having trouble putting some pieces together. There are plenty of blogs out there detailing the code, but none of them from start to finish.

I would like to take the data entered into two text boxes and submit the data on a button push to a list. This is an example of what I grabbed off the blo:

```
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://website url/" ))
// Or SPContext.Current.Site.Url
{
    using (SPWeb Web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
            Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

            // Open List
             SPList list = Web.Lists["MyList"];
        // Add new item in List
             SPListItem item = list.Items.Add();
             item["Title"] = "Test Title";
             item["Description"] = "Test Description";
             item.Update();

            // Get Item ID
             listItemId = item.ID;

            // Update the List item by ID
             SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(listItemId);
             item["Description"] = "Update Description";
             item.Update();

            // Delete item
             SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(listItemId);
             item.Delete();

            Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SPList list = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["MyList"]; //Instead of MyList use name of your list
SPListItem newItem = list.Items.Add(); //Adding new item to the MyList
item["Title"] = "Test Title"; //Title is the field name
item["Description"] = "Test Description"; //Description is the field name
item.Update(); //Saving the new item
```

The above code will add a new item in the List, you need to change the name of the list accordingly... ["Title"] and ["Description"] are the field names, so whatever fields/columns you have in the list, you can assign the values using `ListItem["FieldName"] = value` (Here field name is Internal, [more on Internal, Static and Name properties of field](http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2009/04/static-name-vs-internal-name-vs-display-name-in-sharepoint/))

**EXTRA INFORMATION**
If you are using Visual Web Part SPContext.Current will have the current context... Current context has all the information like the User currently logged in, the SPWeb user is currently in and so on!

Comment: I understand how this code works, I'm just not sure how to deploy it.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio and SharePoint are you using? If its SP 2010 with Visual Studio 2010, you can simply right-click the Project and click deploy to deploy your Visual Web Parts!

Comment: Hi Arsalan, Thanks for the reply. I wasn't sure what tools I needed to deploy this, I just found out I need a copy of Sharepoint server to create custom web parts using VS for my employer. Not sure that will happen.

Comment: @Ghoztrider exactly you will need VS to develop custom Visual Web Parts and deploy them.